# Problem with having uppercase letters for text file fscanf

Tags: c, scanf

Ok, so i've been working on a fscanf code and was stuck on an issue. so when we use convert to uppercase what do we use? My code here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
FILE* input_file = fopen("file1.txt","r");

if (input_file == NULL){
    printf("Unable to open input file\n");
    return 1;
}
   
    char line[1000];
    while( fgets(line, 1000, input_file) != NULL ){
        //maybe
        int length = strlen(line);
          if (line[length-1] == '\n'){
              line[length-1] = '\0';
          }
        //
        for(int i = 0; line[i] != '\0'; i++){
            if (line[i] == '\n'){
                line[i] = '\0';
            }
        }
         printf("%c\n", toupper(line*));
    }

fclose(input_file);
input_file = NULL; 
return 0;
}
```

I've tried using toupper but wont work... the text file i have is:

```
Tomorrow, and tomorrow, and tomorrow,
Creeps in this petty pace from day to day,
To the last syllable of recorded time;
And all our yesterdays have lighted fools
The way to dusty death. Out, out, brief candle!
Life's but a walking shadow, a poor player
That struts and frets his hour upon the stage
And then is heard no more. It is a tale
Told by an idiot, full of sound and fury
Signifying nothing.
```

Which i was able to copy but i can't find out how to get it to captialize.... Also can anyone show me how you would put for total word character and alphabetical characters? Becuase i want to see how that works... Currently i'm getting an[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06FG7.png)

Comment: Like, require all the text file words to become capital letter

Comment: put `printf("%c\n", toupper([i]));` in the for(int i...) loop

Comment: Please post errors as text not screen shots.  The image shows a syntax error on `line*`.  `toupper()` requires a `int`, and `line` is `char *`, so first letter would be `*line` or `line[0]`.  It's poorly formatted which makes it hard to read.  You have find first letter of each word and then toupper it.  `strsep()` might be helpful.

Comment: could you show me how you did it? im getting confused

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to uppercase the input, use the fact that `toupper()` does the right thing (i.e. nothing) for non-letters:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LEN 1000

int main() {
    FILE *input_file = fopen("file1.txt","r");
    if(!input_file) {
        printf("Unable to open input file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char line[LEN];
    while(fgets(line, LEN, input_file)) {
        for(int i = 0; line[i]; i++) {
            line[i] = toupper(line[i]);
        }
        printf("%s", line);
    }
    fclose(input_file);
    return 0;
}
```